# Booting into Linux from an SSD

Tags: linux, ssd

I am trying to create a generic build of software for my students who come to class with all kinds of Windows, and Macs. What's the easiest way to format and prepare an SSD so that it will be able to boot onto a MacOS as well as a Windows computer?

Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: It isn't. What is it that you'd teach them?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The first statement suggests students bring in their own computer, and will run your software on it. The second talks about SSDs and booting into other operating systems. Are you suggesting that you will provide each student with an SSD? Or make them reformat their computers?

Comment: I would provide them with a formatted Ssd. They are shockingly inexpensive these days.

Comment: this may help .... https://www.howtogeek.com/213396/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-drive-on-your-mac/

Comment: Have you verified that it's possible to install an SSD into all of these computers which I'm assuming are laptops? There are a lot of MacBooks that will be using nvme/m2 SSDs and won't have SATA ports. This can also potentially open your institution up to being liable for damages should something happen to a student's computer after installing the SSD and Linux. If you are trying to teach them Linux or something of the sort, I'd advise setting up some VMs for them to SSH into instead of installing hardware and software into their personal computers.

Comment: I’m talking external SSDs, with a usb connection.

Comment: Then I'd still advise against it for the second reason. It's not a good idea to do things like that with peoples' personal computers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly I think you should look into [Docker.](https://www.docker.com/)